# Google Maps Streetview - retrieving geolat/geolng

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

In Google Maps Streetview (V3) the Pitch, Heading and Zoom can be read by monitoring the event

```
google.maps.event.addListener(panorama, "pov_changed", function() { 
     var panoInfo       = panorama.getPov();

      // Picth etc
      document.getElementById("orgpit").value=panoInfo['pitch'];
      document.getElementById("orghea").value=panoInfo['heading'];
      document.getElementById("orgzoo").value=panoInfo['zoom'];
});
```

But when the position changes in Streetview, how can I retrieve the new geolat/geolng as well?

Comment: `panorama.getPosition()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```
var pano = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('yourPanoDiv'), yourPanoOptions);

google.maps.event.addListener(pano, 'position_changed', function() {
  var yourNewPosition = pano.getPosition(); // a google.maps.LatLng object
  // do something with yourNewPosition like
  // alert(yourNewPosition.lat()+" "+yourNewPosition.lon());
});
```

Try also the event 'pano_changed' instead of 'position_changed', to find out which one better fits your needs.